# Default statement in SystemVerilog Case

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, register-transfer-level, vlsi

I'm trying to understand following scenario:

```
typedef enum logic [2:0] {
   ONE, TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE
} enum_t;
```

A case statement with `enum_t` type in case expression:

```
enum_t case_expression;
logic [2:0] result;

case (case_expression)
   ONE: result = 3'b000;
   TWO: result = 3'b001;
   THREE: result = 3'b010;
   FOUR: result = 3'b011;
   FIVE: result = 3'b100;
endcase
```

I'm not sure or clear about following :

- Is it okay not to have a **`default case`** statement for **`result`**? The **`case_expression`** is an **`enum`** with only 5 valid values. However it's 3 bits. So how the synthesis tool will evaluate this logic? Is it going to infer latch ?
- All case items are mutually exclusive. So can I use **`unique`** keyword here to aid synthesis tool to optimize the design?

I don't have much expereince in synthesis. So I would appreciate any feedback. Thanks!

Comment: Since you're using systemverilog, you can put the case statement inside an always_comb. This will ensure that the synthesis tool will infer a combinational logic and never a latch.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on how strongly typed your synthesis tool is. Unfortunately, there are a number of ways that your case_expression could have the value 3'b111 (through casting and poor error checking in some simulation tools). So its best to put the default in for safety's sake.

Comment: You can, but `unique` doesn't help here. There is no possible way your case expression could match multiple case items.

Answer (score 0):

If "case_expression" takes the value "x", the case statement will not be able to resolve which case to enter. If default case were to be mentioned, it would gracefully enter the default case. You will see runtime error if case_expression takes value of "x" if default is not mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

I believe "unique case" is a directive to synthesis tool mentioning all cases are enumerated. This would prevent a latch. If in simulation if none of the ENUM values are on the case expression, then during simulation a runtime error will be reported.